# Enums in GraphCool? How to use them? No Documentation

Tags: enums, graphcool

*GraphCool doesn't have much documentation on Enums*, so I am just posting my Enum info for those who could use it:

**Enums are** arguments of an object that can only have specified values. GraphCool also, to my knowledge, requires them to be defined with a default value.

An **example Enum** is (write them in the enums tab):

```
enum PublishersEnum {
     PEARSON
     WILEY
     MCGRAWHILL
}
```

An example **type with enum**:

```
type Book {
  ...
  publisher: PublishersEnum @defaultValue(value: PEARSON)
  ...
}
```

**Recommendations/conventions**:

Use all caps to help distinguish enum usage.

Name the enum with "Enum" in the name somewhere

**Concerns**:

I have not had good luck with the graph cool interface, when I try to migrate from a string to an enum, the migration value and such didn't work well, hopefully others will have better luck.